# Comparing string and boolean in Expression language

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic, el

I have this behaviour I do not really understand

```
${someVar}
${someVar.class.name}      
${someVar == 'error'}
```

outputs

```
false
java.lang.Boolean
true
```

1. How can it be exlpained?
2. What it the correct way to write the test in order to first test if the two 'things' have the same type and then if their value is the same?

Comment: Removed the old test case and replaced witha more compact and straightforward one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the behaviour of the language as defined in the [EL specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245):

> ## A {==,!=,eq,ne} B
>
> - *other rules elided*
> - If A or B is Boolean coerce both A and B to Boolean, apply operator
>
> ## Coerce A to Boolean
>
> - If A is null or "", return false
> - Otherwise, if A is a Boolean, return A
> - Otherwise, **if A is a String, and Boolean.valueOf(A) does not throw an exception, return it**
> - Otherwise, error

So, the string literal is coerced to a boolean via `Boolean.valueOf("error")` which [returns false](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 6):

If one of the both sides in EL is a `Boolean` (or `boolean`) and the other side is a `String`, then the `String` will be parsed to `Boolean` by `Boolean#valueOf()` whose [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) says the following:

> Returns a `Boolean` with a value represented by the specified string. The `Boolean` returned represents a `true` value if the string argument is not `null` and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true".

So, it returns `false` and this is indeed equal to `false`.

You need to rewrite your EL expression to take into account that the type can be both a boolean and a string, or just to stick to a single type and not to mix types in a single attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As for point 2.

```
<c:set var="errorString" value="${'error'}" />
${someVar.class == errorString.class}
```

will check that the two 'things' are instances of the same class.

But it might be better to convert `someVar` to string, and then compare the two strings, since (at least in my case) someVar is not guaranteed to be a String or a Boolean, so it could be anything else that can be converted to a String.

```
<c:set var="strsomeVar">${someVar}</c:set>
//${someVar}
//${someVar.class}
//${someVar == 'error'}
```

Which outputs

```
//false
//class java.lang.String
//false
```