# Iterating over an ArrayList with c:foreach (JSP/JSTL), Variable doesn't work

Tags: jsp, arraylist, foreach, jstl, loops

There are countless examples out there for my problem, I know, but I went through a lot of them and can't figure out where my mistake is.

I am iterating over an ArrayList(TestSzenario). The class TestSzenario contains a String Variable called name with proper getters and setters.

Here's my code:

```
<td><select name="selectSzenario" id="selectSzenario" size="1">
                <c:forEach items="<%=testszenario.getSzenariosForSummary() %>" var="szenario"> 
                    <option>${szenario.name}</option>
                </c:forEach></select></td></tr>
```

My Problem is, the Variable isn't working. I alwas get ${szenario.name} for every option in the select-box. I declared the JSTL-taglib properly and since there are multiple options in the site when done i know the iteration is working. Also I looked in the HTML-sourcecode an the foreach is resolved.

HTML-output:

```
        <tr><td>Szenario:</td>
        <td><select name="selectSzenario" id="selectSzenario" size="1">

                    <option>${szenario.name}</option>

                    <option>${szenario.name}</option>
                </select></td></tr>
```

EDIT for answer 1:
Thank you, but I tried that before:

```
ArrayList<TestSzenario> szenarioList = testszenario.getSzenariosForSummary();
request.setAttribute("aList", szenarioList);
request.setAttribute("ts", testszenario);

<c:forEach items="${aList}" var="szenario">
<option>${szenario.name}</option>
</c:forEach></select></td></tr>

<c:forEach items="${ts.szenariosForSummary}" var="szenario">
<option>${szenario.name}</option>
</c:forEach></select></td></tr>
```

But in either case it doesn't even iterate through the List, resulting in only 1 option (the List contains 2 elements).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<%=testszenario.getSzenariosForSummary() %>` will convert the object to `String` using `String#valueOf(Object)` method and write it straight to the HTTP response. This is not what you want. Even more, you should **not** be mixing oldschool *scriptlets* with modern taglibs/EL at all.

You need to make sure that `testszenario` is available to EL `${}`. So, just set it as an attribute of page, request, session or application scope beforehand in some servlet like so

```
request.setAttribute("testszenario", testszenario);
```

Then you can just access it the usual way:

```
<c:forEach items="${testszenario.szenariosForSummary}" var="szenario">
```

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - Hello World #2 may be useful to you
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

---

**Update**: as to the problem of EL not being interpreted, you've apparently a mismatch between JSTL and container/`web.xml` version. Make sure that the versions are properly aligned. E.g. Servlet 3.0 container, `version="3.0"` in `web.xml`, JSTL 1.2. See also our JSTL wiki page.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) - read the section "Help! The expression language (EL, those `${}` things) doesn't work in my JSTL tags!"

Comment: You were right, the whole declaration was missing in the web.xml. I didn't read the JSTL Wiki all the way through. Thank you very much, sir!

Comment: @BalusC, doesn't the bit about `<%=testszenario.getSzenariosForSummary() %>` converting the object to a string and printing it to the HTTP response only apply to scriptlets *outside* of JSTL tags? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93408/test-attribute-in-jstl-cif-tag and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684162/how-does-a-scriptlet-pass-an-array-to-a-jstl-tag