# c:forEach doesn't print map contents in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

Disclaimer: I've spent today researching this simple problem inside and out all across stachoverflow and beyond so please bear with me.

I have the following code on JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="com.contrast.db.Manager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>


<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>



<%
    Integer age = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("age"));

%>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>


</head>
<body>


<%

    Manager db = new Manager();
    Connection conn = db.getConnection();


    if (null == conn) {
        out.println("Connection to MySQL failed");
    } else {
        out.println("Connection to MySQL succeeded");
    }

    Map<String, Integer> namesAndAge = db.findByAge(age);

%>

<h1>List of users older then <% out.println(age); %></h1>

<% out.println(namesAndAge); %>

<c:forEach items="${namesAndAge}" var="entry">
    Key = ${entry.key}, value = ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>


</body>
</html>
```

This code for intents and purposes should print out the contents of the HashMap returned by `db.findByAge(age)` but it doesn't

Understandably one could assume that HashMap could be empty, but it's not (please see screen shot below)

[image: Screenshot of the webpage]

As you can see the HashMap is not empty but  is not working

Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over an ArrayList with c:foreach (JSP/JSTL), Variable doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625738/iterating-over-an-arraylist-with-cforeach-jsp-jstl-variable-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the scriplets you declare objects, while in EL expressions what are referenced are attributes in a context (pageContext, request, session or application).

change this line:

```
Map<String, Integer> namesAndAge = db.findByAge(age);
```

For this:

```
request.setAttribute("namesAndAge", db.findByAge(age));
```

Comment: Thank you very much areus, you're saviour!